# n-th child affecting every n-th child no matter how nested

Tags: jquery, html, css

So I am using the `nth-child` selector to insert an iframe. The basic logic is `.selector-div :nth-child(3)` where I would select the 3rd child of the div and insert the iframe. The problem is that when I use this selector is will traverse nested elements and look for any 3rd child of nested elements. For example here is a basic structure of the code

```
<div class='selector-div'>
    <p>random text</p>
    <p> text here
        <a>link</a>
        <b>keyword</b>
        <em>iframe also placed here</em>
    </p>
    <p>iframe here</p>
    <p>more text</p>
</div>
```

I do not want the iframe to be embed in that `<em>` element but the selector is putting it there as well. Any suggestions?

I tried using `:nth-of-type` and `p:nth-child` but I need the insertion of the iframe to be the 3rd element.

Comment: That's how CSS works. You might look at the child selector (`>`) as a limiting device.

Comment: If you're actually asking about your jQuery selector, please show some.

Comment: Thank you! I was missing the child selector, appreciate the help